# Simplify algebraic equation in CAS

Tags: sympy

I want to be able to simplify the ellipse equation:

sqrt((x + c)^2 + y^2) + sqrt((x - c)^2 + y^2) = 2a

into its canonical form:

x^2/a^2 + y^2/(a^2 - c^2) = 1

using CAS. I actually want to know how to do that in sympy, but any other CAS will do.

If it is not possible to do that in one call, then may be by transforming the original equation using operations like "get square of the both sides; move non-radicals (e.g. by enumerating them manually) to the right side; get square of the both sides again; simplify"

Comment: Your asking this in the wrong place try a math centric forum on stackexchange.

Answer (score 3):

unrad will do most of the heavy lifting for you in SymPy:

```
>>> l  # your original expression with the 2a subtracted from the lhs
-2*a + sqrt(y**2 + (-c + x)**2) + sqrt(y**2 + (c + x)**2)
>>> unrad(_)
(-a**4 + a**2*c**2 + a**2*x**2 + a**2*y**2 - c**2*x**2, [], [])
>>> neg_i, dep = _[0].as_independent(x,y)
>>> xpart, ypart = [dep.coeff(i**2) for i in (x,y)]
>>> Eq(-x**2*cancel(xpart/neg_i)-y**2*cancel(ypart/neg_i), neg_i/neg_i)
y**2/(a**2 - c**2) + x**2/a**2 == 1
```

Comment: `unrad` is not importable with `from sympy import unrad`. It's currently burried in `sympy.solvers.solvers`, but perhaps it should be moved to the simplify module and imported by default.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the doubled second sqrt from both sides.
Multiply respective sides of the new equation and the original one.
Reduce LHS applying (m+n)(m-n) = m^2 - n^2.
You'll get (if i did it right): -4xc = 4a(a - sqrt(something))
Then: -xc/a = a - sqrt(something)
and: sqrt(something) = a + xc/a
Square both sides and see what happens.

I did it wrong. Should be: 4xc = 4a(a - sqrt(something))
so sqrt(something) = a - xc/a.

Comment: The question was how to do that in CAS.

Comment: It's same level of CAS as your hint: 'like "get square of the both sides; ... get square of the both sides again; simplify"'